# Reason for DomDocument Document is Empty in Entity in line 3

Tags: php, domdocument, libxml2

I am working on a project and i see a code there as follows...

```
$dom_obj = new DOMDocument();
$dom_obj->loadHTML($html_content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$html = $dom_obj->saveHTML();
```

In this code if i pass $html_content as empty string i can see a warning as follows..

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input
```

Which is expected. But i see sometimes the following error when i pass a normal HTML as well...

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Document is empty in Entity, line: 3
```

i could not able to understand but this warning comes once in a while. It is not happening all the time. anyone have any idea on what occurance this 'Document is empty in Entity' error comes ?
Any help would be appretiated.